# Access is Denied in cmd prompt shp2pgsql

Tags: postgresql, sql, command-line

I was wondering if anyone has come across the error access is denied in command prompt when wanting to load a shapefile using shp2pgsql for postgresql.

I have set my user access security level to bare minimums,  given every single user/admin etc.. full rights to the shapefile folder and command prompt.  I am puzzled to what it could be.  I have fairly heavy firewalls but I don’t think that should be preventing access.

Comment: worth a shot.. try running the command prompt as admin http://www.thewindowsclub.com/how-to-run-command-prompt-as-an-administrator

Comment: check that you are hitting the PG db as the correct user

Comment: what access? file access or DB access?

Comment: I ran the command prompt as administrator, did not receive the error again but it didn’t enter the db.

Answer (score 1):

To make a long story short.  I had to change security permissions for role: 'Everyone' for command prompt and PostgreSQL download file.  **This eliminated the access denied error.

Next I couldn't transfer my shapefile into the SQL database because it was reading the username to the previous version of software that I had uninstalled.  Going to the psql help "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.6\bin> shp2pgsql -I -s 26918 C:\Database\CVEN\StLawrenceRiverAtlas\OriginalData\Railroad.shp railroad2017 | psql --help" in command prompt allowed me to realize what username was being read.

Thank you all for your amazing suggestions!  I appreciate everything!  You just saved me 20 points on my graduate school homework assignment.

Answer (score 0):

If the file is located on a network drive use [UNC Paths](https://www.pcmag.com/encyclopedia/term/53398/unc) not mapped network drives

for example not

`F:\path\to\file`

use:

> `\\serverName\path\to\file`

to see the server names open CMD and type `net use`

Comment: The file is on my c drive .  C:\database\cven\stlawrenceriveratlas\originaldata\railroad.shp

Comment: can you post the exact error and command your trying to execute?

Comment: C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.6\bin>shp2pgsql -I -s 26918 C:\Database\CVEN\StLawrenceRiverAtlas\OriginalData\Railroad.shp railroad2017 | psql - U postgres -d CVEN1 > railroad_data.sql
Access is denied.